# Function not found during import that is certainly present in pygeotools

Tags: python, importerror, projection, gdal, osgeo

A library I'm using called `pygeotools` is throwing a gdal error in running one of the functions. I can't figure out if the issue is on my end, or in the package itself.

In code below `file_path` is the path to a Geotif file. Any file will do.

```
    import pygeotools

    file_path= #path to a geotif file        
    pygeotools.warplib.memwarp_multi_fn(file_path)
```

It throws this error
[image]

BUT, inside the pygeotools.warplib, gdal is called from osgeo. And osgeo definitely contains the function `ReprojectImage`. What is happening here?

[image]

If you need to install `pygeotools`, it can easily be done via `pip install pygeotools`. I've already tried updating pygeotools; it reports that all dependencies are up-to-date. My version of pygeotools is 0.2.0.